# Question in Do Carmo 1-2

Tags: differential-geometry

In Manfredo Do Carmo's *Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces*, Section 1-2, he asks:

> Let $\alpha: I \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a smooth curve that does not pass through the origin.If $\alpha(t_0) \in \alpha[I]$ is the point at which $\alpha(t)$ is closest to the origin and $\alpha'(t_0)\not= 0$, then $\langle \alpha(t_0),\alpha'(t_0) \rangle = 0$

How do we obtain this solution? It would seem intuitively that as $t_0$ is the point at which $\alpha(t_0)$ is minimal, the tangent vector at that point must in some sense lead 'away' from the origin.

Comment: Yes, such that $\alpha(t_0)$ satisfies the said properties.

Comment: Look at the map $\phi:t\mapsto \dfrac{1}{2}\|\alpha(t)\|^2$.
Now, you can interpret the fact that $\alpha(t_0)$ is closest to the origin as an extremum (a minimum in your case) of a differentiable function at $t_0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $(\langle \alpha(t), \alpha(t)\rangle)'=2\langle \alpha(t), \alpha'(t)\rangle$.